# How to show the store name in the grid in the Magento

Tags: magento

I have my custom module in the admin. I have listed the values from the database in the grid. The values are store specific, so every row have the store_id. While listing the value, i also want to display the store name and website name in the row. How can i fetch the store_name and website name in the grid. e.g i have the store_id 5 inserted in the row.

I want the output like

Location        Value      Store

xyz              xyz        English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put below code in your module grid file then you are able to display Store name in your grid, here's a code

```
$this->addColumn(’store_id’, array( 
‘header’ => Mage::helper(’sales’)->__(’Website’), 
‘index’ => ‘store_id’, 
‘type’ => ‘store’, 
‘width’ => ‘100px’, 
‘store_view’=> true, 
‘display_deleted’ => true, 
));
```

Further Information you can refer this [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/228845/#)

Comment: Hello, if you can help me, i have another query regarding this. Listing of store is nice but while listing of the records which are in all the stores, the value is coming blank. I want to show "All sores" in this condition. How can i do this filtering?

Comment: So you should check condition while saving store_id if all store is selected then store all store ids comma seprated or vice versa so you can able to get all store listing on grid

Answer (score 0):

So you have `store_id` and you want to display the store name right ?

So use below code to get the store name

```
$storeId = 5;
$storeName = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getName();
```